# How to combine query_string and range of timestamp in elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have two query. One is searching in logmessage and second time in range of timestamp.

```
query = {
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "logmessage:test"
        }
    }
```

and

```
query = {
    "query": {
"range" : {
            "@timestamp" : {
                "lte" : "2017-08-04"
            }                   
        }
    }
```

How I can create one with both options ? I tried this:

```
    query = {
        "query": {
            "query_string" : {
                "query" : "logmessage:test"
            },
    "range" : {
                "@timestamp" : {
                    "gte" : "2017-08-04",
                    "lte" : "now"
                }                   
            }
        }
    }
```

but with no success. There is some 400 error because of bad syntax I guess

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for a bool query https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html. You can compose multiple queries into one using should, must, must_not and filter clauses:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "lte": "2017-08-04"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "logmessage:test"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hi man it is another problem but you can help me again. I noticed that I sill got just 2000 result in query. How I can change to get more

Comment: size:3000 should do the trick https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html

Comment: ok never mind paramter in query is overided what I wrote as es.search parameter